# URL Rewrite/Reverse Proxy of Friendly Names IIS 7 and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url, iis-7, proxy, url-rewriting

My Configuration looks like this:

Server A is hosting a website - sitea.com
It is also reverse proxying to Server B that is hosting a Blog site.

The reverse proxy works just fine, if I navigate to sitea.com/blog it takes me to server b.  I set up friendly names on Server B for the blog posts.  If I Navigate to server b from a browser the Friendly names work, with out issue, but if I navigate to the blog posts from Server A, I get a page cannot be found.

Any ideas?